# What can be the equivalent of entity in .NET Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

The core works perfectly in ASP.NET MVC but I have problems in ASP.NET Core near "Entities" - please  help

```
public ActionResult AddOrEdit(int id = 0)
{
    SELECTEDEMPLOYEE emp = new SELECTEDEMPLOYEE();

    using (Entities db = new Entities())
    {
        if (id != 0)
        {
            emp = db.SELECTEDEMPLOYEEs.Where(x => x.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();
            emp.SelectedIDArray = emp.SELECTEDEMPLOYEEIDS.Split(',').ToArray();
        } 

        emp.EmployeeCollection = db.VIEW_USER.ToList();
    }

    return View(emp);
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you're having? Please [edit] your question to include the desired behavior and the exact error or issue you're experiencing. Questions without proper debugging details like these may end up being [closed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) or [deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions)

Comment: keywork "Entity" is not recognized in .netcore,however same code works nice in asp.net mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe in your second project you do not have Entity class (context class).